# Minecraft Pe 0.11.1 online server world loading problem

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I got a problem in my minecraft pe. Whenever I try to connect servers like lbsg the server world doesn't loads just I see is a blank world with some people. Whereas my brother who plays on same network but different mobile can play without any loading issues. We both use 2g networks (speed max 25 kbps).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too but when I switched my skin back to the default Steve it seemed to load up and work fine.